# Blender takes a long time syncing objects

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Why does Blender take more time synchronizing than it does to render. Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

A screen shot of the sync screen:
[image: Syncing]

Comment: Only by this screenshot I can only say that nearly 8 000 000 faces are causing this. Meshes are to heavy. I don't know if you use some modifiers along this and what textures you have used.

Answer (score 5):

If you used cycles, then you can enable `Persistent Data` under `Render Properties` >`Performance` > `Final Render`. This way, only for the first frame object synchronization is performed or when the objects are changed. It comes at the cost of increased memory usage. See also [here](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.93/Cycles)

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a solution, but does help me speeding up the animation render.

In my case one object needs a lot of time to synchronize. While this is happening the computer is not really busy. To use these ressources I started a 2nd instance of blender (background render at the commandline) starting rendering the 2nd half of the animation. This increased the render time of both render instances just a little bit which in general accelerates the animation render almost by a factor of two.

I don't know how that is influenced by the specific scene and the hardware used. But for me it worked pretty well.

Comment: Good idea, could you provide some insight on when or why the synchronizing takes long.

Comment: At the moment I don't exactly know what blender is doing when synchronizing an object. It probably has something to do with the number of vertices and maybe with the texture applied to the object (and UV unwrapping). This is probably a good new question.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue across the board.
My solution is:

- Clean all un-used nodes in material editor.
- Make instances real
  where it's possible. (on object level go to "apply, make instances
  real")
- reduce texture files to the absolute necessary (i had lots of 4k textures in a 4K composition but technically I would need less for optimal display)
- under file- external data - PURGE all external stuff that is not used in the scene
- save the file, quit and re-open it.